# Seeking clarity for notation about norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I came across this exercise which I will state in full to avoid any confusion:

> Denote $B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $[0,1]$, and $M([0,1])$ be the space of real finite measures $\mu: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with norm $||\mu|| = |\mu|([0,1])$. Show that $M([0,1])$ is a real Banach space.

I've looked everywhere in my notes but I couldn't find the meaning of the notation $|\mu|([0,1])$. Shouldn't it just be $\mu([0,1])$, i.e., the measure of $[0,1]$ wrt $\mu$? What does $|\mu|$ even mean?

Comment: Look at Rudin's RCA for definition of $|\mu|$.

Comment: Notice that you are in the space of **real** finite measures and NOT non-negative finite measures. The notation $\left| \mu \right|$ simply means taking that absolute value of the total measure of $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$.

Comment: $\mu(A)$ can have negative values. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_in_measure_theory

Comment: Ok thank you for all the information, this is totally new to me.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh You are wrong. $|\mu| [0,1]$ is not $|\mu [0,1]|$. That is a big mistake and misleads OP.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Based on the wikipedia link and a little tweaking of notation, I believe it should be $$|\mu|([0,1])=\sup\{\mu(A):A \subset [0,1]\} + |\inf\{\mu(A):A \subset [0,1]\}|$$ where $A$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1]$ wrt $\mu$. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: That is correct, There are also what are called complex measures and there is a more general definition of the measure $|\mu|$. See Rudin's book.

Comment: $||\mu||$ is the measure-theoretic analog of the $1$-norm eg $||(a,b)||_1 = |a| + |b|$.  $\mu$ may give positive or negative values but in some sense (eg Mason's answer below) $||\mu||$ is given by taking absolute values everywhere and then adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total variation of a complex measure $\nu$ is the positive measure $|\nu|$ uniquely determined by the condition that if $\mu$ is a positive measure and $d\nu = f\,d\mu$, then $d|\nu| = |f|\,d\mu$. See chapters 3.1-3.3 of "Real Analysis" by Folland.